# String.contains not working

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to filter a list based on input from a textbox. If the item doesn't contain the string, it is deleted from the list. Here is my subroutine:

```
 Sub filterlists(filter As String)

    Dim removalDifferential As Integer = 0
    For colE As Integer = 0 To RadListView1.Items.Count
        Try
            Dim itemEpp As ListViewDataItem = Me.RadListView1.Items(colE)
            Dim jobname As String = itemEpp(0)

            If Not jobname.Contains(filter) Then

               ' MsgBox(jobname & " Contains " & filter)
                RadListView1.Items.RemoveAt(colE - removalDifferential)
                removalDifferential = removalDifferential + 1
            End If
        Catch
        End Try

    Next
End Sub
```

Currently this is not deleting the correct items. The TRY is there because when you delete an item the list index changes (which means the for loop length is wrong and will throw outofbounce errors). Any other loop options that will work here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your title makes it sound like you think you've found a bug in String.Contains.

Comment: Try `For colE As Integer = RadListView1.Items.Count To 0 Step -1`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you really do want to delete any LVI which simply contains the filter text, you should loop backwards thru the items (any items, not just Listview items) so the index variable will in fact point to the next correct item after a deletion:

```
For n As Integer =  RadListView1.Items.Count-1 to 0 Step -1
    If radListView1.Items(n).Text.Contains(filter) Then
        RadListView1.Items.RemoveAt(n)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I am dealing with multiple columns in this case, so I used 
Dim jobname As String = itemEpp(0)

Thanks alot!

Comment: in that case, click the checkmark to mark this as answered and earn yourself some rep as well